# Android: Opening wrong Activity from the widget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, widget, android-pendingintent

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now. I have a widget which displays summary of a cooking recipe. The widget is clickable so whenever user clicks on it the new activity is opened with a full description of that recipe. The problem is that sometimes when the widget is clicked it opens a wrong activity. Let me give you an example:

1. User clicks on widget and activity A is opened
2. User starts activity B (e.g. recipe index) from the activity A.
3. User starts activity C from activity B.
4. User presses Home button.
5. User clicks on the widget again and the activity C is displayed instead of A

I tried setting a compibation of those three flags which helps in solving only a half of the problem:

```
openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

By using above flags I managed to display a correct activity (A) until I do the following:

1. User opens activity A from the widget
2. User moves to activity B and opens activity A by clicking on new recipe
3. New recipe is displayed to the user
4. User clicks Home button and clicks on the widget.
5. Activity A is displayed (the right one) but with different recipe.
6. From now on if I move to different activities B or C and click Home and then widget again the activity A is not displayed but the one which was visible before pressing Home button.

I hope I explained it in enough details. I would be really grateful for your help because this thing drives me crazy!

**Updated:**

This is my pendingIntent:

```
Intent openIntent = new Intent(context, ProfanityDefinition.class);

openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
openIntent.setData(Uri.parse(openIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("widgetRequest", true);
openIntent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_content, openPendingIntent);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Show the code for creating the `PedningIntent`. If you are passing extras to your activity, be aware that two intents that differ only by extras are treated as equivalent. You probably want  to pass the `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when you create the `PendingIntent` to make sure your intent is not reused.

Comment: Since a task for you activity is already running, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` will just bring the running activity to the foreground. Set `android:taskAffinity=""` in AndroidManifest.xml for the `ProfanityDefinition` activity to cause it to run in a separate task. Then you will get a new instance on clicking the widget.

Comment: That didn't help... I still get activity B instead of A or A with different content...it's strange

Comment: It works, check your code. Are you using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` as the flags? And what is the class name of 'activity A'?

Comment: I was missing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag - it works! thanks!